# How can I use a script to call a binary object using an aws_instance within terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm creating multiple aws_instances using terraform's count looping ability. I wish each of these  instances to run a script which requires a custom binary. The script calls the binary a user specified number of times with some fixed parameters but I don't think the specifics of what it's doing is relevant to the question

I have been able to create a bucket:

```
# Create an S3 bucket to hold foo binary and bar script
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "foobar-bucket" {
  bucket = "foobar-bucket"
  acl    = "private"

  tags = {
    Name        = "Foobar Bucket"
  }

}
```

Upload the script and binary to said bucket:

```
# Upload foo binary to S3 bucket
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "foo-object" {
  bucket = "foobar-bucket"
  key    = "foo"
  source = "./misc/foo" # local file location

  depends_on = [
    aws_s3_bucket.foobar-bucket,
  ]
}

# Upload bar script to S3 bucket
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "bar-script" {
  bucket = "foobar-bucket"
  key    = "bar.sh"
  source = "./misc/bar.sh"

  depends_on = [
    aws_s3_bucket.foobar-bucket,
  ]
}
```

Then using remote-exec downloaded the script and binary and called the script:

```
resource "aws_instance" "default" {
  count = 10
...
    provisioner "remote-exec" {
      inline = [
        "aws s3 cp s3://foobar-bucket/foo ./",
        "aws s3 cp s3://foobar-bucket/bar.sh ./",
        "chmod +x foo bar.sh",
        "sudo ./bar.sh 100",
      ]
    }
...
}
```

This works as expected, all the s3 access etc is set up correctly however it doesn't seem like the correct solution, especially as terraform's docs suggest provisioner and remote-exec should be last resort options.

What is the correct way to provision files on an ec2 instance and run scripts using terraform? S3 seemed like a good solution to only upload the files once and allow as many ec2 instances to access as necessary, but maybe there's a better solution again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [user_data](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance#user_data) option in `aws_instance` resource?

```
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami           = "ami-0c55b159cbfafe1f0"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  user_data = <<-EOF
              #!/bin/bash
                aws s3 cp s3://foobar-bucket/foo ./
                aws s3 cp s3://foobar-bucket/bar.sh ./
                chmod +x foo bar.sh
                sudo ./bar.sh 100
              EOF
  tags = {
    Name = "terraform-example"
  }
}
```

If the script is a bit lengthy and you prefer to have that defined in a completely different file

**run_commands.sh**

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
aws s3 cp s3://foobar-bucket/foo ./
aws s3 cp s3://foobar-bucket/bar.sh ./
chmod +x foo bar.sh
sudo ./bar.sh 100
```

```
resource "aws_instance" "my-instance" {
    ami = "ami-04169656fea786776"
    instance_type = "t2.nano"
    key_name = "${aws_key_pair.terraform-demo.key_name}"
    user_data = "${file("run_commands.sh")}"
    tags = {
        Name = "Terraform"  
    }
}
```

Comment: IIRC change of userdata triggers resource change. Maybe `cloud-init` could load additional data during its start.